# Change Image background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jcomponent

How can I change the color of the background image that is black to the color that is selelected?

```
JComponent colorBar = new ColorComponent(Color.BLACK);
colorBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Color defaultColor = getBackground();
            Color selected = JColorChooser.showDialog(DessinFrame.this,
                    "Set background", defaultColor);
            if (selected != null) setBackground(selected);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Close. It looks like your get/setBackground(selected) should be referencing the colorBar component

```
JComponent colorBar = new ColorComponent(Color.BLACK);
colorBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Color defaultColor = colorBar.getBackground();
            Color selected = JColorChooser.showDialog(DessinFrame.this, "Set background", defaultColor);
            if (selected != null) colorBar.setBackground(selected);
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi, if you want you can add me to skype mine is andresgc12. and i give you my class because i dont want to pubish that, but this code have an error i put it

Comment: What is the error?? Sorry, I'm not in a position to get on Skype.

Comment: it said rename in a file or put it final

Comment: Well try putting it final and seeing if it works. You can always refactor the code to prevent the final requirement.

Comment: Can you please upload your code somewhere and I can take a peek at it

Comment: i have now some difficulties to draw rectangles and ellipse!